# Graph theory: determining maximum number of edges

Tags: graphs

Based on the question below, can someone please explain to me the reasoning behind why the maximum number of edge is 5/2|V|? I don't find the particular reasoning in the solution to be that helpful for why the maximum number is 5/2|V|.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Can you point out the very first statement or, in fact, the very first concept in that reasoning that does not make a lot of sense to you? That will help readers help you a lot. In fact, if you can think about them step by step, concept by concept, statement by statement, you might be able to figure it out by yourself. Also, drawing a graph that specializes the argument may help you, too.

Answer (score 1):

The following identity is well-known:
$$
2|E| = \sum_{v \in V} d(v).
$$
In words, if we sum all degrees in a graph, we get twice the number of edges. To see this, divide each edge $(x,y)$ into two halves: the $x$-half and the $y$-half. We think of the $x$-half as a half-edge labeled $x$. The left-hand side counts the number of half-edges. On the right-hand side, $d(v)$ counts the number of half-edges labeled $v$, and so in total, the right-hand side also counts the number of half-edges.

If the graph has maximum degree $\Delta$ (in your case, $\Delta = 5$) then
$$
2|E| = \sum_{v \in V} d(v) \leq \sum_{v \in V} \Delta = \Delta |V|,
$$
and so $|E| \leq (\Delta/2) |V|$; there is equality if the graph is $\Delta$-regular (all degrees are exactly $\Delta$).